# R spread data frame

Tags: r, pivot, spread

I have this data set dput:

```
structure(list(Account.Name = c("CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", 
"CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", 
"CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "CMD", "Colimbra", 
"Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", 
"Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", 
"Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", 
"Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", 
"Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", "Colimbra", 
"Colimbra"), Date.y = structure(c(47L, 38L, 39L, 46L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 37L, 36L, 34L, 43L, 45L, 41L, 42L, 33L, 40L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 
35L, 44L, 26L, 9L, 24L, 17L, 23L, 18L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 10L, 
7L, 11L, 35L, 25L, 19L, 16L, 34L, 27L, 4L, 26L, 20L, 29L, 15L, 
33L, 32L, 30L, 14L, 22L, 31L, 13L, 21L, 28L), .Label = c("", 
"2012-12-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", 
"2013-05-01", "2013-06-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-09-01", 
"2013-10-01", "2013-11-01", "2013-12-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01", 
"2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", 
"2014-08-01", "2014-09-01", "2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", 
"2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", 
"2015-06-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-08-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-10-01", 
"2015-11-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-08-01", 
"2016-09-01"), class = "factor"), EI = c(0.172413778757433, 0.283582069077747, 
0.304347804744803, 0.278195468486632, 0.675675653544559, 0.965738751378275, 
0.79789472055251, 0.571428546702807, 0.364238387240035, 0.333333310925928, 
0.333333310925928, 0.267175552791797, 0.30935249644739, 0.30935249644739, 
0.547169786306516, 0.342465730716834, 0.25581393431044, 0.593220290504169, 
0.529411739555941, 0.538461513372782, 0.333333310925928, 0.119266044513089, 
0.00689655157368212, 0.0932835783248028, 0.117967327490881, 0.111415832683409, 
0.0864661618980282, 0.0170648454887846, 0.0380999488912474, 0.00803673911715819, 
0.0500855092066307, 0.00942675138629104, 0.0201612894472413, 
0.0046082948309584, 0.00435339299151454, 0.144554447192982, 0.0830188645366324, 
0.0825861213183505, 0.0129474483080438, 0.0240963850193243, 0.00917431152659711, 
0.0215175530933231, 0.0953932023013541, 0.00917431172607524, 
0.0873239401148782, 0.00892174336861008, 0.018429689070739, 0.0352357312529589, 
0.0470588220329153, 0.059847657373831, 0.00588084875970071, 0.0479921625133198, 
0.229030327296333, 0.00613496919149197)), .Names = c("Account.Name", 
"Date.y", "EI"), row.names = c(69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 95L, 96L, 99L, 101L, 104L, 105L, 107L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 113L, 114L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I need to spread it (pivot it) in such way that each row will be one Account.Name and each column will be the related Date.y column with a column name starting from 0_date (if it's the last Date.y date value for that account) and ending with i_date (i is the index of the first date record for the account counting from the end to the beginning).
for instance:

Account.Name date_0, date_1, date_2...
CMD 0.333333311 0.333333311 0.309352496

- where date_0 corresponds to 2016-06-01
  date_1 corresponds to 2016-05-01
  date_2 corresponds to 2016-04-01
  and so on ...
  I tried to use tidyr::spread however, the column name are assigned to the original date values, and I want to make a relative date columns names (counting from 0_date, 1_date until last date for each account)
  Any idea appreciated

Comment: Can you show the full expected output?  Have you tried `library(reshape2);dcast(df1, Account.Name~Date.y, value.var="EI")`

Comment: if I had the full expected output, I wouldn't be here. Is there something specific that's you don't understand in the expected output ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you wanted because the minimum and max date in the dput output is `"2013-02-01"` and `"2016-09-01"`.  So how is `date_0` corresponds to "2016-06-01"`.  Also, if you have looked at other posts with reproducible examples, most of them provided the expected output (perhaps by manually creating it) so that others understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let x be your data frame

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(x)
# date should not be factors
dt[, Date.y := ymd(Date.y)]  
setorder(dt, Account.Name, -Date.y)
dt[, col_index := 0:(.N-1L), by = Account.Name]
dt_casted <- dcast(dt, Account.Name ~ col_index, value.var = "EI")
```

Note I didn't use "date_0" format because I believe you will want them sorted, while "date_10" will have wrong order compare to "date_2". Better keep the index as numeric, or pad with leading 0.